# Different ways to accomplish chat on iPhone

Tags: iphone, chat

I was having a look at [Ray Wenderlich's](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server) tutorial to create a simple chat application using **socket programing** which is quite interesting.

There is also [XMPP Framework](http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/) which enables us to have chat feature in our application. I was wondering if there are other ways or more frameworks through which we may implement chat feature in our application.

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing your own chat protocols you need to implement some kind of tcp server that will forward and route message data that will have some kind of TLV and routing information. You can associate the routing information with a username.

or you can go with [XMPP.](http://home.gna.org/xmpp4r/)

To get more idea go with below demo apps:

1. [x-ioschat](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-ioschat/index.html)
2. [my-first-iphone-app-xmpp-chat-client](http://tharindufit.wordpress.com/2009/01/18/my-first-iphone-app-xmpp-chat-client/)
3. [latest-chatty-2](https://github.com/Squeegy/latest-chatty-2)